# Reducing Memory Usage in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

How can I reduce tomcat memory usage. Just with the default webapps, the tomcat usage is above 70MB. Is there any way to reduce this memory usage?

Let's say I want to use tomcat as servlet container only, where the servlets return JSON or XML or String, strictly no HTML or JSP. Is it possible to disable JSP, sessions, etc. in Tomcat? Which I think might reduce tomcat's memory footprint.

Tomcat Version: 7.0.22  Servlets: 3.0

Comment: Regardless of how much you strip it down, you still have to have the entire JVM loaded.

Comment: Could you Please tell me how to strip it down , Let me have a try

Comment: If its just about returning JSON/ XML then you are building an API only server. If you try node.js it starts from 20MB.